# Gpars.withPool threads eventually stops executing after iterating numerous times

Tags: groovy, gpars

Was trying to execute concurrent operations with Gpars.

```
Gpars.withPool(6) {
  someList.eachParallel {
    println "${Thread.currentThread}"
  }
}
```

Initially it seems to work

```
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main] 
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6,5,main] 
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]  
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5,5,main] 
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4,5,main] 
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-6,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
```

But after iterating for sometime, some of the threads stops executing.

```
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main] 
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main] 
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
```

Until eventually we are left with only one.

```
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
```

Any idea why this happens? Any solution to keep all threads active?

In my case, it might be worth mentioning that we are iterating at around 50k-200k.

Comment: have the other threads finished their work? how many lines are printed out?

Comment: Yes they have. I'm quite sure they are not stuck on doing something. Since on my tests they are just printing.

Comment: With regards to how many times, I believe it is able to complete the number of iterations intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case other people have the same issue. Their documentation says:

> Because GParsPool uses a Fork/Join pool (with work stealing), threads may not be applied to a waiting processing task even though they may appear idle. With a work-stealing algorithm, worker threads that run out of things to do can steal tasks from other threads that are still busy.
>
> if you use GParsExecutorsPool , which doesn't use Fork/Join, you get the thread allocation behavior that you would naively expect.

Base on that, I opt to use GParsExecutorsPool instead. With this, all threads executed consistently until the end of the whole eachParallel process.

```
GParsExecutorsPool.withPool(6) {
  someList.eachParallel {
    println "${Thread.currentThread}"
  }
}
```